# freeradius 3 mac auth user group (for configuration simplicity)

Tags: freeradius

I have implemented Radius MAC authentication with Unifi AP and freeradius.  I am using Radius primarily to set the vlan that the device should sent to allowing a consolidated SSID to handle multiple vlans.  (This is a home network, not an enterprise so I am not concerned with the mac spoofing situation).  Any MAC connecting will get a vlan (but non-radius users will go to a guest vlan by default)

The freeradius question is how I can go about assigning a group value to each MAC user definition and then post-auth use that group name to define the specific attributes such as Tunnel-Type, Tunnel-Medium-Type, and Tunnel-Private-Group-Id.  I simply want to do this to avoid having to repeat all these tunnel values for each device.

Example (not sure if syntax is right)

authorize file
`AABBCCDDEEFFGG Group := "iot", Cleartext-Password := "AABBCCDDEEFFGG"`

site-enabled/default (I think it might go here)

`if (group == "iot) { #update reply, set Tunnel-* values }`

Any guidance someone could provide would be great.  All the examples I have found seem to be using the mysql backend and I don't have a need for the additional complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using control variables.  Here is the solution.

1. Create a custom attribute in the dictionary file.

   `ATTRIBUTE       VLAN-Group-Name         3000    string`
2. Add users to the authorize file like so

   `AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF Cleartext-Password := "AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF", VLAN-Group-Name := "iot"`
3. In your virtual server, in my case it was sites-enabled/default, look for the post-auth section and add code similar to this.  You will replace the group-id XXX with your vlan # you want sent back to the AP to be assigned.  I placed the code right above the -sql portion.

```
switch "&control:VLAN-Group-Name" {
    case "iot" {
        update reply {
            Tunnel-Type = 13,
            Tunnel-Medium-Type = 6,
            Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = XXX
        }
    }
    case "general" {
        update reply {
            Tunnel-Type = 13,
            Tunnel-Medium-Type = 6,
            Tunnel-Private-Group-Id = XXX
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to keep the authorize file clean with just users and assign them a group and keep the group values simplified in the post-auth.  If you ever needed to change the vlan # of any group just one update and restart.

Cheers!